# this not working in async function in React component

Tags: reactjs

In my React component `this.login()` isn't executing. I believe this is because an `await function` changes the context of this, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
           await this.props
                .SignupUser({
                    variables: {
                        email: this.state.email,
                        password: this.state.password,
                        name: this.state.name,
                    },
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.login();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.setState({ wait: false });
                    const errorMessage = error.graphQLErrors[0].functionError;
                    this.setState({ error: errorMessage });
                });
```

Comment: is there any error in API call.Did you checked in catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `await` keyword, It should work.

Alternatively, we need to implement in a different way

The function must add `async` keyword in the function declaration for below code

```
 await this.props
    .SignupUser({
        variables: {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
            name: this.state.name,
        },
    })
    .then(() => {
        this.login();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ wait: false });
        const errorMessage = error.graphQLErrors[0].functionError;
        this.setState({ error: errorMessage });
    });
```

(or)

```
    try {
    const user = await this.props
        .SignupUser({
            variables: {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password,
                name: this.state.name,
            },
        });
    this.login();
} catch (e) {
    this.setState({ wait: false });
    const errorMessage = error.graphQLErrors[0].functionError;
    this.setState({ error: errorMessage });
}
```